# Fotorama.io how to resize navigation dots?

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

There is no explanation on the Fotorama.io website how to change size of the navigation dots menu down the page. See  [example](http://fotorama.io/examples/full-window-n-nav.html) of use

Comment: [please show what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: i tryed add this in css file `.fotorama__dot {
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  left: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid; 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are default values. you can change to with your own values.

```
.fotorama__nav--dots .fotorama__nav__frame {
  width: 18px;
  height: 30px;
}

.fotorama__nav__frame.fotorama__active .fotorama__dot {
}

.fotorama__dot {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I tryed edit this in css file but with no effect. U can change .fotorama{} and .fotorama__nav {} only. See my website code at http://zygmuntkamzol.pl/Wroclaw3.html

Comment: but arkusz.css file loads before fotorama.css. change their order. you should call arkusz.css after  fotorama.css or width: 8px !important; height: 8px !important;

Comment: yes it works! see result online. if u click there on larger dot then small dot appear i wanna change it too. u know how to change that?

Comment: @Denzelq `.fotorama__nav__frame.fotorama__active .fotorama__dot {
border: 2px solid;
background-color: #ff9900;
}`

Comment: add `background-color: #ff9900;` to `.fotorama__dot` , `#ff9900` is hex color. for more colors visit http://www.colorpicker.com/ . i've visited Wroclaw. very beautiful city and good people. if you interested in html,css or etc. it is very easy to learn. but you may start beginning. simple search google and do practices. you can find millions of tutorials